# Windows 2016 AD DC on google cloud platform

Tags: active-directory, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

trying to build a lab on GCP that requires windows 2012/16 AD DS. Does not need to be production grade setup. I was following the instructions mentioned location

[Deploying Microsoft Active Directory Domain Controllers on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-microsoft-active-directory-domain-controllers-with-advanced-networking-configuration-on-gcp)

I have successfully executed that in single node setup and it works perfectly fine. I just have one question. Do I need to setup a separate VPC for this setup? Can't I use the existing VPCs GCP has on different regions? That way I can access internet from DC and also DC is expose to internet for other servers from other cloud providers? What if one of my servers are in AWS and I need to add that server to the domain where DC is hosted on GCP?

Again, it is not production setup. It's just the way my lab is.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the [described setup](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-microsoft-active-directory-domain-controllers-with-advanced-networking-configuration-on-gcp) you do not need a second VPC. You only need to use two subnets in different regions under the same VPC. You can either work with the subnets that are already created in the “default” VPC network or create another VPC network with a couple of new subnets.

Having said that, it is absolutely possible to place your Windows AD DS VMs in different VPC networks and add them to the same domain. If they will only use internal IPs you might need to [implement VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) . As there should be end to end reachability between AD server and the client machine.

If you want your VMs to have access to Internet and be reachable from outside the GCP network you will need to configure them with [external IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). Bear in mind that ephemeral external IPs change each time the VMs reboot and you might need to manually modify your configurations whenever this happens. Depending on your needs it might be better to go with static external IPs. You will also have to implement a set of [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to allow the required ingress traffic so that a Windows AD DS VM hosted in AWS can be added to your GCP Windows AD DS.

Comment: Thanks. With your guidance I could setup windows AD without creating seperate VPC. I used existing network subnet.

Comment: @KunalShah Since my answer worked for you, could you mark it as accepted so that other community users having the same issue will be able to use the same procedure? Thanks in advance.